# Как правильнее сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

В предложении "...причем не простую бабочку, а бабочку-монарх(а)..." - как правильно: "бабочку-монарх" или "бабочку-монарха"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слов **монарх** является согласованным приложением. Приложение - это определение, выраженное именем существительным, согласованным в падеже с определяемым словом (в вашем случае - в винительном падеже). Несогласованными приложениями обычно являются географические и астрономические названия. В вашем случае **монарх** - видовое название насекомого. Нужно писать: *"...причем не простую бабочку, а бабочку-монарха...".*

Answer (score 0):

В качестве запоминалки: при дефисном написании первое слово может и не склогняться, но второе склоняется всегда.

Answer (score 0):

конечно, "бабочку-монарха"